# Trampling with Charge Through

Tags: pathfinder-1e

A Mammont Rider PRC can choose from several mount, some of which have Trample Monster Ability:

> As a full-round action, a creature with the trample ability can attempt to 
>   overrun any creature that is at least one size category Smaller than
>   itself. This works just like the overrun combat maneuver, but the
>   trampling creature does not need to make a check, it merely has to
>   move over opponents in its path. Targets of a trample take an amount
>   of damage equal to the trampling creature’s slam damage + 1-1/2 times
>   its Str modifier. Targets of a trample can make an attack of
>   opportunity, but at a –4 penalty. If targets forgo an attack of
>   opportunity, they can attempt to avoid the trampling creature and
>   receive a Reflex save to take half damage. The save DC against a
>   creature’s trample attack is 10 + 1/2 the creature’s HD + the
>   creature’s Str modifier (the exact DC is given in the creature’s
>   descriptive text). A trampling creature can only deal trampling damage
>   to each target once per round, no matter how many times its movement
>   takes it over a target creature.

However, the rider might as well possess the Charge Through ability:

> When making a charge, you can attempt to overrun one creature in the
>   path of the charge as a free action. If you successfully overrun that
>   creature, you can complete the charge. If the overrun is unsuccessful,
>   the charge ends in the space directly in front of that creature.

Is it possible to use this trample as an element of the charge and would that still be a free action? Would that cause the enemy being trampled to be knocked prone? Also, does that mean that the charge cannot be stopped by unsuccessful overrun attempt? Finally, would that prevent any of the tramplers (the mount or the rider) from attacking normally at the end of the charge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### By RAW, No.

By RAW Charge Through does what it says it does - lets you Overrun (not Trample) one foe.

It is, however, a very reasonable houserule to allow an animal companion with Charge Through (the Charger archetype gives them the ability to choose it as a feat, useless on a rider as it says 'you' not 'your mount') and the Trample special ability to combine the two and automatically 'Trample' any enemies of the appropriate smaller size between it and it's Charge target.

This is, however, a House Rule, and by RAW does not work.